# Class for managing blocks of working hours

Tags: c#, object-oriented, datetime, interval

I have written the following class:

**NOTE:** There is a bug in the third party component that means that if a `DHXBlockTime` is there for a day of the week and a specific date then only the ones with a specific date are shown so that is why there is the seemingly redundant `AddNonWorkingHoursAsDateInsteadOfDay` method.

```
internal  class CalendarHelper
{
    internal static IEnumerable<DHXBlockTime> GetUnavailableBlocks(IEnumerable<Driver> availableDrivers, string viewName)
    {
        var unavailable = new List<DHXBlockTime>();

        foreach (var driver in availableDrivers)
        {
            AddNonWorkingHours(viewName, unavailable, driver);

            foreach (var away in driver.Aways)
            {
                unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
                {
                    StartDate = away.StartDate,
                    EndDate = away.EndDate,
                    Sections = new List<Section>()
                    {
                        new Section(viewName, new string[] {away.EntityPersonStaffId.ToString()})
                    }
                });

                var startDate = new DateTime(away.StartDate.Year, away.StartDate.Month, away.StartDate.Day);
                var endDate = new DateTime(away.EndDate.Year, away.EndDate.Month, away.EndDate.Day);

                var workingHours = driver.WorkingHours.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Active && w.DayOfWeekIndex == (int)startDate.DayOfWeek);
                AddNonWorkingHoursAsDateInsteadOfDay(viewName, workingHours, unavailable, startDate, away.EntityPersonStaffId);

                if (startDate < endDate)
                {
                    workingHours = driver.WorkingHours.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Active && w.DayOfWeekIndex == (int)endDate.DayOfWeek);
                    AddNonWorkingHoursAsDateInsteadOfDay(viewName, workingHours, unavailable, endDate, away.EntityPersonStaffId);
                }

            }
        }

        return unavailable;
    }

    private static void AddNonWorkingHoursAsDateInsteadOfDay(string viewName, EntityPersonStaffHours workingHours, ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable, DateTime awayDate, int staffId)
    {
        if (workingHours == null)
        {
            AddDefaultUnavailableTimes(viewName, unavailable, awayDate, staffId);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!workingHours.IsWorking)
            {
                unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
                {
                    StartDate = awayDate,
                    EndDate = awayDate.AddHours(24),
                    Sections = new List<Section>()
                    {
                        new Section(viewName,
                            new string[] {staffId.ToString()})
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                int startMinutes = 7 * 60;
                int endMinutes = 22 * 60;

                if (workingHours.StartTime != null) startMinutes = (int) workingHours.StartTime.Value.TotalMinutes;
                if (workingHours.EndTime != null) endMinutes = (int) workingHours.EndTime.Value.TotalMinutes;

                unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
                {
                    StartDate = awayDate,
                    EndDate = awayDate.AddMinutes(startMinutes),
                    Sections = new List<Section>()
                    {
                        new Section(viewName, new string[] {staffId.ToString()})
                    }
                });

                unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
                {
                    StartDate = awayDate.AddMinutes(endMinutes),
                    EndDate = awayDate.AddHours(24),
                    Sections = new List<Section>()
                    {
                        new Section(viewName, new string[] {staffId.ToString()})
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddDefaultUnavailableTimes(string viewName, ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable, DateTime awayDate, int staffId)
    {
        unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
        {
            StartDate = awayDate,
            EndDate = awayDate.AddHours(7),
            Sections = new List<Section>()
            {
                new Section(viewName, new string[] {staffId.ToString()})
            }
        });
        unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
        {
            StartDate = awayDate.AddHours(22),
            EndDate = awayDate.AddHours(24),
            Sections = new List<Section>()
            {
                new Section(viewName, new string[] {staffId.ToString()})
            }
        });
    }

    private static void AddNonWorkingHours(string viewName, ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable, Driver driver)
    {
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++)
        {
            int startOne = 0;
            int endOne = 7 * 60;
            int startTwo = 22 * 60;
            int endTwo = 24 * 60;

            if (driver.WorkingHours.Count > 0)
            {
                var workingHours = driver.WorkingHours.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Active && w.DayOfWeekIndex == day);
                if (workingHours != null)
                {
                    if (workingHours.IsWorking)
                    {
                        if (workingHours.StartTime != null)
                            endOne = (int)workingHours.StartTime.Value.TotalMinutes;
                        if (workingHours.EndTime != null)
                            startTwo = (int)workingHours.EndTime.Value.TotalMinutes;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        endOne = 12 * 60;
                        startTwo = 12 * 60;
                    }
                }
            }

            var zones = new List<Zone>();
            if (endOne == startTwo)
                zones.Add(new Zone { Start = startOne, End = endTwo });
            else
            {
                zones.Add(new Zone { Start = startOne, End = endOne });
                zones.Add(new Zone { Start = startTwo, End = endTwo });
            }

            unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
            {
                Day = (DayOfWeek)day,
                Zones = zones,
                Sections = new List<Section>()
                {
                    new Section(viewName, new string[] {driver.ID.ToString()})
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

I am pretty sure that it needs refactored as it is all static methods, but I am not sure how exactly. I think the class should be given a constructor as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<Driver> _availableDrivers;
private readonly string _viewName;

internal CalendarHelper(IEnumerable<Driver> availableDrivers, string viewName)
{
    _availableDrivers = availableDrivers;
    _viewName = viewName;
}
```

And then the `availableDrivers` and `viewName` parameters are not needed on each method and they can become instance methods rather than static methods, but then I get a class which only has one public method. Another developer has commented that doing this is a needless complication and so I am looking for guidance.

Comment: Why do you believe that static methods are bad?

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't believe static methods are bad, it's just that in this instance I have a chain of calls passing at least a couple of the same parameters - that is what seems bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of repeating code like this:

> ```
> unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime()
> {
>     StartDate = away.StartDate,
>     EndDate = away.EndDate,
>     Sections = new List<Section>()
>     {
>         new Section(viewName, new string[] {away.EntityPersonStaffId.ToString()})
>     }
> });
> ```

Define a method that will do all this stuff:

```
private static void AddUnavailableBlockTime(ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable,
                                            DateTime startDate,
                                            DateTime endDate,
                                            string sectionViewName,
                                            int sectionDriverId,
                                            IEnumerable<Zone> zones = null)
{
    unavailable.Add(new DHXBlockTime
    {
        StartDate = startDate,
        EndDate = endDate,
        Zones = zones,
        Sections = new List<Section>
        {
            new Section(sectionViewName, new[] { sectionDriverId.ToString() })
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
private static void AddDefaultUnavailableTimes(string viewName, ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable, DateTime awayDate, int staffId)
{
    AddUnavailableBlockTime(unavailable,
                            awayDate,
                            awayDate.AddHours(7),
                            viewName,
                            staffId);
    AddUnavailableBlockTime(unavailable,
                            awayDate.AddHours(22),
                            awayDate.AddHours(24),
                            viewName,
                            staffId);
}
```

As for this code:

> ```
> int startOne = 0;
> int endOne = 7 * 60;
> int startTwo = 22 * 60;
> int endTwo = 24 * 60;
> ```

you should definitely extract all this values to named constants since it is unclear what these magic numbers mean.

And finally I recommend to change `List<DHXBlockTime>` everywhere in your code on `IEnumerable<DHXBlockTime>` and use `yield return` to produce result collection. It is not good to pass changeable collection between multiple methods. For example `AddUnavailableBlockTime` will be turned into

```
private static DHXBlockTime GetUnavailableBlockTime(DateTime startDate,
                                                    DateTime endDate,
                                                    string sectionViewName,
                                                    int sectionDriverId,
                                                    IEnumerable<Zone> zones = null)
{
    return new DHXBlockTime
    {
        StartDate = startDate,
        EndDate = endDate,
        Zones = zones,
        Sections = new List<Section>
        {
            new Section(sectionViewName, new[] { sectionDriverId.ToString() })
        }
    };
}
```

and `AddDefaultUnavailableTimes` will become

```
private static IEnumerable<DHXBlockTime> GetDefaultUnavailableTimes(string viewName, DateTime awayDate, int staffId)
{
    yield return GetUnavailableBlockTime(awayDate,
                                         awayDate.AddHours(7),
                                         viewName,
                                         staffId);
    yield return AddUnavailableBlockTime(awayDate.AddHours(22),
                                         awayDate.AddHours(24),
                                         viewName,
                                         staffId);
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to change private static void AddNonWorkingHours(string viewName, ICollection<DHXBlockTime> unavailable, Driver driver) to private static List<DHXBlockTime> GetNonWorkingHours(string viewName, Driver driver) and then use unavailable.AddRange(GetNonWorkingHours(viewName, driver))?

Comment: Yes, it will be better. But return `IEnumerable<DHXBlockTime>` instead of `List<DHXBlockTime>`.

Comment: Why IEnumerable rather than List?

Comment: If you don't suppose to use members specific for particular type you should use more general type. `AddRange` takes `IEnumerable<T>` as an argument, so what is the purpose of returning a `List<T>`?